# IIS6 returning 404 for all requests containing "Translate:f" header

Tags: iis-6, webdav

I have written a custom WebDav implementation which is now hosted in IIS6, which now accepts "Translate:f" as a header but as it does so bypasses my custom http module (ASP.NET 3.5) and returns a 404 error.

It is correct that there is no resource at the given address, but my custom module should be handling the request - it seems that the "Translate:f" header causes IIS6 to bypass it and go straight for the resource.

I can't prevent the app from sending "Translate:f" as a header but is there any way of configuring IIS6 to always run my module even if it sees this header.

Cheers,

Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own differently worded question

[Is it possible to configure IIS6/7 to ignore certain request headers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/198523/is-it-possible-to-configure-iis6-7-to-ignore-certain-request-headers/198537#198537)