# Is it possible to configure IIS6/7 to ignore certain request headers?

Tags: iis, iis-6

I currently have a problem that would be easily resolved if I could configure IIS6 to somehow ignore certain request headers. Namely "Translate:f". It should process the request as if that header wasn't even there.

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Can you use mod_headers in the .htaccess file in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a useful iis implementation of the apache mod_headers. Not free but have used one of their products before and was satisified.

http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_headers.htm